# Streaming video on iOS from GAE Blobstore keeps pausing (won't buffer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-app-engine, video-streaming, blobstore

I have uploaded videos to the blobstore in quicktime format and am now trying to stream them on ios by passing the serving url to an AVPlayerItem

```
[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL: https://myapp.appspot.com/serveVideo?blob-key=key]
```

On the backend my code is:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException {
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
    res.addHeader("Content-Type", "video/quicktime");
}
```

If I paste the url into the browser I can stream videos. On iOS our videos show up and buffer a little then pause. If I manually set a timer and tell the video to keep playing every 4 seconds `[self.player play]` the video keeps playing. If I pass a url to a YouTube video instead to the AVPlayer the video plays smoothly. Any idea how to get videos to stream smoothly from the blobstore on ios?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615086/avplayer-play-pause-and-buffering-issue

Comment: Yes, I still think streaming from the blobstore is slower than it should be but using an observer for playbackLikelyToKeepUp and only continuing the video when it changed to "YES" I was able to at least stop the glitchy feel.